# Sorry query limit to google place reached. error ocuure in google query

Tags: android

i have try to find near all places of currant location. some times **"Sorry query limit to Google place reaches"** error is occurred. how solve that problem ... ?? or what is alternative solution of this problem... i using this query to find near places of `current location`..

```
private static final String PLACES_SEARCH_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?";
private static final String PLACES_TEXT_SEARCH_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?";
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a limit to how many times per hour (I think its hour, it may be more) that google allows you to call its maps API with a given key.  You're going over.  There really is no solution other than to call it less or get Google to allow your key a higher limit (they may sell extra access).

Make sure you don't have multiple apps using the same key, that would cause them all to get the same shared limit.

Comment: Thanx a lot... but how can i get a my key to higher query limit.. and my application is also multiple user.

Comment: According to the google places usage page, they allow 1000 querries per API key per day for unverified accounts, 100K querries for verified ones.  So verify your account.  If you need more than that, email google and be prepared to pay.

Comment: According to google API. I was verify a google account key but can't take permission of more query per day as u suggest me.